# Reading Windows ACLs from Java

Tags: java, windows, security, acl

From within a Java program, I want to be able to list out the Windows users and groups who have permission to read a given file. Java has no built-in ability to read the Windows ACL information out (at least until [Java 7](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/Attributes.html#getAcl%28java.nio.file.FileRef%29)), so I'm looking for other solutions.

Are there any third party libraries available which can provide direct access to the ACL information for a Windows file?

Failing that, maybe running cacls and capturing and then processing the output would be a reasonable temporary solution - Is the output format of cacls thoroughly documented anywhere, and is it likely to change between versions of Windows?

Answer (score 6):

[mdma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326480/mdma)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2815574/18437) covers the best approaches for Java 6 but here's a quick example for Java 7:

```
Path file = Paths.get("c:\\test-file.dat");
AclFileAttributeView aclFileAttributes = Files.getFileAttributeView(
    file, AclFileAttributeView.class);

for (AclEntry aclEntry : aclFileAttributes.getAcl()) {
    System.out.println(aclEntry.principal() + ":");
    System.out.println(aclEntry.permissions() + "\n");
}
```

Comment: thanks, I am getting user details from the folder security,I also need the email address for the users and the group. is any way to get that

Answer (score 5):

If you know the windows APIs, you could use [JNA](http://jna.dev.java.net) (JNI without the hassle of writing native code) to call the Windows APIs to get the ACL data.

Altenatively here is [an article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295004) that gets the file security details using VBScript. You could modify this, and have it return the details in a parsable format (e.g. XML). You can invoke a VBScript file by running "cscript.exe", using Runtime.exec() or [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). You can write the ACL info to standard output, and use the streams available on the `java.lang.Process` to read the process output.

Although exec'ing vbscript might seem a bit hacky, it will get you off to a quick start, since most of the code is already written and working (I presume - I haven't tried the script in the article.) Using the script also avoids needing to map the relevant Win32 apis to java via JNA.