# change directory owner in java

Tags: java, windows, winapi

How to change directory owner of directory in Windows using API can deal with Java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a file itself, it's easy, but for a directory, you can't (as far as I know) do it through Java because it's dependent on the file system (e.g. FAT, NTFS, HFS+, ext4, etc.). Sorry.

Just in case you meant for a file.

From the Java documentation for [Files.setOwner(File, UserPrincipal)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setOwner%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipal%29):

> Usage Example: Suppose we want to make "joe" the owner of a file:
>
> ```
> Path path = ...
> UserPrincipalLookupService lookupService =
>     provider(path).getUserPrincipalLookupService();
> UserPrincipal joe = lookupService.lookupPrincipalByName("joe");
> Files.setOwner(path, joe);
> ```

Also look at the [Managing Metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) section of the Java tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to use cacls.exe. Also an interesting discussion here that would be applicable for writing acls/owners too:

[Reading Windows ACLs from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815523/reading-windows-acls-from-java)

Edit: actually, cacls won't handle ownership. This is better: https://serverfault.com/questions/27332/how-to-take-ownership-of-files-from-the-command-line